# How to properly trigger geofence?

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, location, android-geofence

Im trying to make an app where i can understand when a user enter/exit some specific geofences,but time is important .

How i can trigger this event (enter/exit a geofence) ?

Can i use fused Location API in order to save battery as a foreground service ? Can Fused location work without gps ?

Also if i run it every 5 minutes how i can minimize this gap in order to avoid bugs (if user exit in that specific 5 minute gap).**Any ideas - alternatives ?**

Thanks .